# How to turn off Document Recovery in Word if I shut down without closing?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013

When I shut down/sleep the laptop without closing Word, next day I get the Document Recovery panel with the files I was using before shut down.
I already unchecked in *Word Options-->Save* "Save AutoRecover information". In fact all options in Save panel are unchecked.
I have Windows 7.

Comment: Sounds like there might be a problem with your files. Technically, you should not have to go through that each time you open a file. Can you be more specific? Does this happen with one specific file or all files?

Comment: @CharlieRB Well, not every time. This morning it appeared for the first file I opened (being notified for two files I used yesterday) and not for the rest.

Comment: Are these files from a previous version? If so, do a "save as" to the new format and see if it fixes the issue? If it doesn't, try a repair installation of Office.

Comment: @CharlieRB I have edited my question